# Wrong rectangle drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I probably don't understand rectangle drawing using TikZ. The code bellow shows clear drawing, but even if those `\g` and `\w` are same, output file is wrong.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \a {3}
\def \w {0.5}
\def \g {0.5}
\def \s14 {0.5}
\def \s34 {0.5}

\filldraw [blue] (0,0) rectangle (\a, \a);
\filldraw [white] (\w,\w) rectangle (\a - \w,\a - \w);
\filldraw [yellow] (0,\a/2 + \g/2) rectangle (\w,\g);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I made some notes on output drawing. The yellow area is unwanted, position and size of the g x w rectangle is clearly shown. Can you help?

Comment: This is not the problem, but what are the two different definitions of `\s` for? Note that the numbers are not part of the macro name as macro names can only consist of an arbitrary amount of alphabetic letters OR a single character that is not alphabetic.

Comment: not related as you do not use `\s` but `\def \s14 {0.5}
\def \s34 {0.5}` just defines `\s` twice and it will give an error if not followed by `34`

Comment: Should I use different notation? Does these numeric sufixes make trouble?

Comment: @JanFilip In short: Yes they do. If you now want to use the macro `\s` it has to be followed by `34`, else results in an error. But there is no macro called `\s34` defined. Only two definitions of `\s` with the latter being used as it overwrites the first one. In TeX without further tricks a macro can't be named with mixed alphabetic and numeric characters. What you could do is use roman numbers.

Comment: using `\def` also means that you silently over-ride latex internals with no warning, so defining `\a` for example will break most text accents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want this? You can use `+` to tell Ti*k*Z that the second coordinate is
relative to the first.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand* \mylengthA {3}
\newcommand* \mylengthW {0.5}
\newcommand* \mylengthG {0.5}


\fill [blue] (0,0) rectangle (\mylengthA, \mylengthA);
\fill [white]
  (\mylengthW,\mylengthW) rectangle
  (\mylengthA - \mylengthW,\mylengthA - \mylengthW);
\fill [yellow]
  (0,\mylengthA/2 + \mylengthG/2) rectangle +(\mylengthW,-\mylengthG);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`rectangle` draws a rectangle between the two coordinates given. Without `+` they are considered to be absolute and not relative to each other. So `\draw (1,1) rectangle (2,2);` would draw a rectangle between those two points with edges of 1cm length.

Comment: Exactly :), can you edit your post and provide some reference link to manual please?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: @Skillmon, it seems that better (corect) result is obtained, if you use only `\fill` instead `\filldraw`. also, if coordinate after `++` is not used in further image construction, it is sufficient only one `+` sign: `\fill [yellow] (0,\a/2 + \g/2) rectangle +(\w,-\g);`

Comment: @Zarko thank you for the corrections. I'll edit my answer.